# Why submit button on the form is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have downloaded a sample form which is this:

```
  <form id="login-user"  method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="/home.html" class="simform">
    <div class="sminputs">
      <div class="input full">
        <label class="string optional" for="user-name">Email*</label>
        <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-email" placeholder="Email" type="email" size="50" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sminputs">
      <div class="input full">
        <label class="string optional" for="user-pw">Password *</label>
        <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw" placeholder="Password" type="password" size="50" />
                                <span class="hide-password">Show</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="simform__actions">
      <input class="sumbit" name="commit" type="sumbit" value = "Log in"/>
      <span class="simform__actions-sidetext"><a class="special" role="link" href="#">Forgot your password?<br>Click here</a></span>
    </div> 
  </form>
```

When I press on submit button it is not working and it will click on text onside the button! But when I change this line

```
<input class="sumbit" name="commit" type="sumbit" value = "Log in"/>
```

To

```
<button class="sumbit" name="commit" type="sumbit" value = "Log in"/>
```

It is working but my css design will be change.

My other question is, I was wondered if CSS file can have effect on functionality of html page. I thought it only effect on design and look of form. Is it effecting on functionality as above?

**EDIT**

Here is my javascript

```
$("#login-user").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Here");
        var name = $("#user-email").val();
        var pass = $("#user-pw").val();

        Parse.User.logIn(name,pass,{
            success: function(user){
                checkLogin();
                alert("Thanks for login");
                window.location.href = "/home.html";
        }, error : function(user, error){
            console.log("Login Error : " + error.message);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the right one.

```
 <button class="sumbit" name="commit" type="submit" value = "">
  Log in
 </button>
```

your `type="sumbit"` is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Correct. Stupid mistake.

Comment: We all do make stupid mistakes sometimes.. glad to help you. =)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should change as following.

```
 <button class="sumbit" name="commit" type="sumbit" value = "Log in"/>
```

to

```
<button class="sumbit" name="commit" type="sumbit">Log in</button>
```

Reference for you http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Comment: What's `type="sumbit"`?